# Is it possible to have a computed property based on DateTime.now in Mobx?

Tags: flutter, mobx

I'm currently trying this in Dart/Flutter, but I think the concept is the same in other languages.

Consider that 'expires' receives a date representing 2 days from now, so 'expired' is true and should change to false when 2 days passes.

```
@observable
DateTime expires;

@computed
bool get expired =>
      expires == null ||
      expires.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds <= 0;
```

When running the app, this property does not change from true to false, but in my unit tests, it does, and that's why I don't know if this is possible or not.

Unit test for reference:

```
test('when expires pass its due date, it should trigger expired',
    () async {
  state.changeExpires(
    DateTime.now().add(const Duration(seconds: 3)),
  );

  expect(
    state.hasTokenExpired,
    isFalse,
    reason:
        'because expires ${state.expires.toIso8601String()} should be in the interval expected to not be expired',
  );

  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));

  expect(
    state.hasTokenExpired,
    isTrue,
    reason:
        'because expired ${state.expires.toIso8601String()} has not expired',
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be achieved with a stream. Here is an example and [direct reference from mobx's flutter repository](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx.dart/issues/633#issuecomment-792052360).

```
class TimeStore = _TimeStoreBase with _$TimeStore;

abstract class _TimeStoreBase with Store {
  @observable
  DateTime expired = DateTime.now();
  @observable
  ObservableStream<DateTime> _time = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1))
      .map((_) => DateTime.now())
      .asObservable();

  @computed
  DateTime get now => _time.value ?? DateTime.now();

  @computed
  bool get expired => expires != null && expires.difference(now).inSeconds <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For JS there is a nice utils library `mobx-utils` with similar function `now()` that will update all observers, reactions and etc.

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils/blob/master/src/now.ts

Maybe you could try to implement it for Dart.

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction, the example I've got from mobx's flutter repo is similar to the one in the now.ts. Thank you!